# (Java) Returns a new string version of the current string where all the letters either >= or <= the given char n, are removed

Tags: java, loops, char

Returns a new string version of the current string where all the letters either >= or <= the given char n, are removed.

The given letter may be a-z or A-Z, inclusive. The letters to be removed are case insensitive. If 'more' is false, all letters less than or equal to n will be removed in the returned string. If 'more' is true, all letters greater than or equal to n will be removed in the returned string.
If the current string is null, the method should return an empty string.
If n is not a letter (and the current string is not null), the method should return an empty string.

Questions: Since the method receives char n, how do I apply for loop to each character? Do I use arrayOfArg and is it correct to use arrayOfArg[i] ++ to store letters more than the letter?

```
public String filterLetters(char n, boolean more) {
    char [] arrayOfArg = n.toCharArray();
    String myNewString = "";
    String removedChar = "";
    
    if (n == null) {
        return "";
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < Character.length; i++) {
        if (more == false) {
            //all letters less than or equal to n will be removed in the returned string
            if (Character.isLetter(i) == true) continue;
            removedChar = arrayOfArg[i] ++;
            myNewString = arrayOfArg.replace(removedChar,"");
                
        }
        if (more == true) {
            //all letters less than or equal to n will be removed in the returned string
            if (Character.isLetter(i) == true) continue;
            removedChar = arrayOfArg[i] -- ;
            myNewString = arrayOfArg.replace(removedChar,"");
        }
    }
    return myNewString;
        }
```

Comment: "Since the method receives char n, how do I apply for loop to each character? " What?  A char is a SINGLE character.  Your question does not make sense.  If you received a STRING, then sure, you could use `toCharArray()` to get all the chars from it.

Comment: @Idle_Mind I think OP has omitted to provide the string parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This is a slight modification to the code you requested but the output works properly. I'm sure someone else has a better idea than me. This is just a starting place.

```
public static String filterLetters(String word, String n, boolean more) {
    String[] alphabet = new String[]{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"};
    int charValue = 0;
    //Find Numerical Value of Char n
    for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++) {
      if (alphabet[i].equalsIgnoreCase(n)) {
        charValue = i + 1;
      }
    }
    if (more) {
      for (int i = charValue; i < alphabet.length; i++) {
        word = word.replaceAll(alphabet[i],"");
      }
    } else {
      for (int i = charValue; i > 0; i--) {
        word = word.replaceAll(alphabet[i],"");
      }
    }

    
    return word;
  }
```

Comment: U have assumed that the letters to be removed are the alphabets in lower case.... But as per the question the `char n` could be even lower /upper case...And more over it is not specified... From which string or whatever he wants to achieve is not clearly told

Comment: If you look, I used .equalsIgnoreCase(). Which does just that. It ignores upper case or lower case.

Comment: no i am questioning you ....why have you assumed that the 'LETTERS' to be removed from are the "ALPHABETS"

Comment: You don't need `replaceAll()`. `replace()` will do, because you aren't using a regex search parameter (and `replace()` still replaces *all* occurrences).

Comment: @daksh because OP said *If n is not a letter (and the current string is not null), the method should return an empty string*

Comment: I appreciate it Bohemian! I'm quite new to coding as I'm sure you could tell by the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Use regex!

```
public String filterLetters(String str, char n, boolean more) {
    if (str == null || !Character.isLetter(n)) {
        return "";
    }
    String range = more ? n + "-z" : "a-" + n;
    return str.replaceAll("(?i)[" + range + "]", "");
}
```

This works by creating a regular expression as follows:

- if `more` is true: `(?i)[n-z]`
- if `more` is false: `(?i)[a-n]`

where "n" is the actual char passed in.

`(?i)` flag turns on case insensitivity.

`[a-n]` is the range (inclusive) of characters from `a` to `n`.
`[n-z]` is the range (inclusive) of characters from `n` to `z`.

Note: The necessary `String` parameter has been added to the method.